# Why "подруга", not "друга"

Tags: этимология, род

I wonder are there any other cases when prefix `по-` indicates feminine gender?
I can recall some nouns with `по-` prefix, like `постель` or `повесть`, but this words have roots that are also feminine.

On the other hand, there are plenty of words with `по-` prefix which are masculine, for example, `поручик`.

So, how come `друг`'s feminine form is `подруга`, can someone shed light on the etymology of this form?

Comment: `постель` и `повесть` are a completely differnt case. `постель` is based on the verb `постелить`, where `по` makes it the perfect form of the imprerfect verb `стелить`. `повесть` is based on `повествование`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Подруга* is a derivative of *подружиться*, compare *полюбовница, побратим* etc.

This prefix is not productive for forming feminine in Russian so this is just an ad hoc form.

CS for this word would be *другиня* and I believe Old Russian had a similar form. In modern Ukrainian it means "wife" (*дружина* in modern form), so most probably *подруга* replaced the old form to separate the meanings.

Comment: In current Ukrainian the word for wife is `дружина`.

Comment: @Dima: yes, the language changes with time.

Comment: @Quassnoi, are you sure that `другиня` is not relatively new form, kind of XVIII century neologism, build by analogy, as богиня or героиня. I've found that it has been used by Vasily Trediakovsky, who is known as a great appreciator of neologisms.

Comment: @shabunc: it's mentioned, for instance, in 1581's Ostrog Bible (Luke 15:9): *и обрѣтши съзываетъ другынѧ и съсѣды глаголющи: радуитесѧ со мною, яко обрѣтохъ драхъму погибшую*

Comment: @shabunc: BTW, Sreznevsky mentions the Old Russian form *друга* in a `XVI` text.

Comment: @Quassnoi, these is a very nice observations, thank you for providing them.

Comment: For what it's worth, the 16th installment in the *Словарь русского языка XI—XVII вв.* series has *подругъ* (masculine): http://i.imgur.com/EtcVl.png

Comment: Rare and almost not usable form is 'товарка'. This is female form of 'товарищ'. Been used at 1920-30 years in former Soviet Union.

Comment: `товарка` is, as you've mentioned, feminine of товарищ, which is not an a exact synonym of подруга. There, for example, exists `прительница` as well. In short, this is not an answer to this question.